# What if I spoof the MAC Address of a public device (such as a router)?

Tags: networking, ip, network-adapter, tcpip

MAC addreess should be unique in a particular network. Manufacturers try to keep this unique, but there is no guarantee. Even we can create a virtual device using software.

My question is, what will happen if someone tries to spoof the MAC address of a system (may be a public server) and connect it to Internet? Won't it break the communication between that server and its clients?

Or are there any safeguards in place so that this won't happen in public networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't break anything unless the server with the spoofed mac address is connected in the same broadcast domain as the 'attacker'.

Mac addresses are only relevant in local networks, they don't pass over what you commonly think of as the 'internet' and so it doesn't matter. Infact, a lot of devices will spoof addresses, which may match other devices which are also spoofing the same address. As long as they aren't in the same broadcast domain (lan, basically) there's no issue.

Comment: Yes, it should be unique in a LAN. My question is, what if it is not unique in Internet (as Internet can be considered as a big network similar to a LAN, but public). So they can be in the same broadcast domain. What if this is manufactured by a spurious manufacturer to spoof the MAC address (or even a virtual MAC address)?

Comment: Mac addresses never pass 'over the internet'. So nothing would happen, literally the mac addresses are never seen so there's nothing to clash.

Comment: Thanks djsmiley2k. I thought this would go over the internet. May be, my understanding is incorrect. So if I configure a device with any MAC address to some public IP and connect in over the Internet, won't it create an issue? I am sure that it won't allow to connect like that - but I am struggling to get the concept. I tried to read few networking stuff including TCP/IP mechanisms, but so far could not get this basic concept. Is there any good resource in Internet where I can get a grasp over this?

Comment: A mac address is what's used by a router, to know which interface to send the data over. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrG7RTWIJak might help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

> MAC addreess should be unique in a particular network.

No, they don't need to be unique — please continue reading.

> Manufacturers try to keep this unique, but there is no guarantee.

No, there IS a guarantee.
Part of MAC address is assigned to a manufacturer, other part is for a manufacturer's free use, so manufacturers takes care to don't duplicate numbers in their part of MAC addresses.

---

**The explanation:**

With some sort of simplification there are

- LANs (Local Area Networks), and
- internetworks (interconnected LANs; abbreviated as “internets” with the Internet as a one of them).

MAC addresses are LAN-specific (so they have to be *unique in the individual LANs*).

Outside of LAN the addressing of networked devices (including routers) is exclusively performed by *logical addressees* (which have to be unique in the whole internetwork).

**So no harm from spoofing *any* MAC address, as long as there is not the same address in its LAN(s).** (Routers are generally connected to more LANs).

---

**Note:**

In TCP/IP, the most common network protocol stack, logical addresses are called *IP addresses* — by the name of a protocol (Internet Protocol) which operates in the Network Layer. See [The OSI Model — Features, Principles and Layers](https://www.studytonight.com/computer-networks/complete-osi-model).

Comment: Thanks Marian for the answer. Even if Internet uses IP as the logical address, you need that to map to a MAC address, right? As per my understanding, you cannot assign logical addresses to random entities if you want to refer to the entities later.

Comment: The relation between logical and physical (MAC) address is known only in LAN. Only in LANs is used the physical addressing (at the Datalink Layer). The addressing for communication from one LAN to the other LAN is following: MAC from a device to a router, IP from the router to the other router, MAC from the other router to a target device.

Answer (score 0):

This "address spoofing" was commonly used if you had a machine connected to an external network, not under your control (think early ISP), which registered the MAC address of the machine (really, network card). If the card broke, it was much easier to get a new one and set it's MAC to the old one's than work your way through the bureaucracy of the ISP. Ditto for a new machine.

The Sun SPARCstations could have several network cards installed, they all got the same MAC assigned (essentially a machine identifier). As long as the different interfaces were connected to different networks, no one was the wiser. Again, it was possible to assign MACs at will.

Some software packages used to be keyed off the network MAC, if that changed, the package supposed to be a pirated copy and refused to work. Again, the solution was to change the MAC. The "official" way of going through the vendor wasn't worth the hassle.

For reasons like the above, most network cards can have their MAC reset in software. That is *can* be done doesn't mean it is a good idea to mess with this.